# How to use plyr mdply with failsafe execution in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr

I have to run an analysis on multiple datasets. I use plyr (mdply) with the doSNOW package to use multiple cores.
Sometimes the analysis code will fail,raising an error and stopping execution. I want the analysis to be continued for the other datasets. How to achieve that?
Solution 1: Coding so that all errors are caught which is not feasable.
Solution 2: A failsafe plyr wrapper to  run the function in parallel that returns all valid results, and indicates where something went wrong.

I implemented the second solution (see answer below). The tricky part was that I wanted a single function call to accomplish the failsafe-and-return-a-data.frame feature.

How I went about constructing the function:
The actual function call is wrapped with `tryCatch`. It is called from within a `callfailsafe` function, which in turn is necessary to pass the individual function name  `simple` and respective parameters in `(...)` to the whole procedure. 
Maybe I did it overly complicated... but it works.

Be sure that your `simple` function does not rely on any globally defined functions or parameters, as these will not be loaded when used with .parallel=T and doSNOW.

Here is my test dataset: There are 100 tasks. For each a function "simple" will be called. However sometimes the function fails. I use it typically on tasks that autonomously load many rdata files do extensive processing, save some output and finally return a data.frame object.

```
library(plyr)
library(doSNOW)
N=100
multiargtab= data.frame(ID=1:N,A=round(runif(N,0,1)),B=round(runif(N,0,1)))

simple=function(ID,A,B){ # a function that will sometimes fail
  if(B==0) rm(B)
  data.frame(A=A,B=B,AB=A/B,ID=ID)
}
```

The signature of the calling function is:

```
res2=mdply.anyfun.parallel.failsafe(multiargtab,simple)
```

Comment: You could also use `try` instead of `tryCatch`; it's much simpler and generally does all that's required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `mdply.anyfun.parallel.failsafe` takes a `data.frame` and a functionname `myfunction` (as character) as parameters. `myfunction` is then called for every row in the data.frame and passed all column values as parameters like the original mdply. Additionally to the original `mdply` functionality the function does not stop when a task fails, but continues on the other tasks. The error message of the failed task is returned in the column "error".

```
library(doSNOW)
library(plyr)
mdply.anyfun.parallel.failsafe=function(multiargtab,myfunction){
  cl<-makeCluster(4)
  registerDoSNOW(cl)

  callfailsafe=function(...){
    r=tryCatch.W.E(FUN(...))
    val=r$value[[1]]
    if(!"simpleError" %in% class(val)){
      return(val)
    }else{
      return(data.frame(...,error= (as.character(val))))
    }
  }

  tryCatch.W.E=function(expr) {
    #pass a function, it will be run and result returned; if error then error will return - BUT function will not fail
    W <- NULL
    w.handler <- function(w){ # warning handler
      W <<- w
      invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
    }
    list(value = list(withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) e),  warning = w.handler)), warning = W)
  }
  FUN=match.fun(myfunction)
  res=mdply(multiargtab,callfailsafe,.parallel=T)
  stopCluster(cl)
  res
}
```

Testing the function:

```
res2=mdply.anyfun.parallel.failsafe(multiargtab,simple)
```

Which generally works fine. I only have some strange errors when multiargtab is of type `data.table`

```
Error in data.table(..., key = key(..1)) : 
  Item 1 has no length. Provide at least one item
```

I circumvented the error by casting as `as.data.frame` ...although it would be interesting to know why data.table would not work.

Comment: Is this the answer to your own question? If it is I would suggest you to add a few lines of explanation what the critical parts were. Otherwise, your answer is not helpful for other. If, however, this just provides additional information for the question above, I would suggest you to reduce the amount of code and put the remaining content in the question body.

Comment: @Thilo suggestion taken. example shortened. I posted it because I think it is a common problem, that has bugged me for a while... but if my solution is not understood, there is no point in posting it. I hope it as become clearer now. thanks for your commment.

Comment: Great! That is what I hoped to see. Changes the -1 to +1 ;)